# fetching processor architecture in mac using uname giving incorrect results when go binary is built for amd64

Tags: go, darwin, rosetta, uname

I have a golang service which needs to fetch processor's architecture type

```
archCmd := exec.Command("uname", "-m")
arch, _ := archCmd.CombinedOutput()
```

I am running the same binary on both intel and arm machines. The binary is built with

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64
```

On arm machines, this fetches x86_64. It seems this is happening since I'm building with GOARCH=amd64. I am not however sure why this would happen.
What's my alternative if i want to run the same built binary on both intel and arm machines.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. But I'm getting those mentioned results

Comment: @aksh02, sorry, I seem to have misread your comment, the child process does also seem run under rosetta, and is seeing the same CPU architecture. What is the problem you are trying to solve though?

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/1735265/443147, but can't mark as such.  Will provide accredited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting a comment from [`@hrdy`](https://superuser.com/a/1735265/443147) that describes this problem:

> Running any kind of EDR which might run on the client under rosetta makes [`sysctl`] the only valid answer since this checks the underlaying machine itself and not the current prompt which might be wrong due to rosetta.

Quoting a separate superuser answer: https://superuser.com/a/1735265/443147

> You can use `sysctl` to get information about your CPU:
>
> ```bash
> sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string
> machdep.cpu.brand_string: Apple M1 Pro
> ```

... this will require some conditional logic to detect OS as well as parsing to detect an Apple CPU type.  This may break in the future if this string value changes.

```
archCmd := exec.Command("sysctl", "machdep.cpu.brand_string")
arch, _ := archCmd.CombinedOutput()
```

Again, credit goes to  [`@selalerercapitolis`](https://superuser.com/a/1735265/443147)'s answer linked.

Comment: This works, still looking for an alternative though to get arm64 or x86_64 results. Marking this accepted for now. Thanks.

Comment: I dug a bit more, but all I can find so far is a bunch of people parsing `sysctl` output, including the [apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659846).  If you find a better approach, there seems to be plenty of people interested.